# Can't redirect to URI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this URI I want to redirect to: `redirect('search_results/result/$id');`

I get this error: `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.`
Do you have any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want use variable within string use double quotation instead of single quotation.

`redirect("search_results/result/$id");`

Comment: Right. Or `redirect('search_results/result/'.$id);`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
redirect('search_results/result/'.$id);
```

Or as suggested above

```
redirect("search_results/result/$id");
```

Even this one

```
redirect("search_results/result/{$id}");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use single quotes - it doesn't substutute the variable value ($id), you need to use double quotes.

Let's see the example:

index.php:

```
<?php

$id=100;
echo 'search_results/result/$id'.PHP_EOL;
echo "search_results/result/$id".PHP_EOL;
```

php index.php

```
search_results/result/$id
search_results/result/100
```